# Parse Play form errors from Scala.js

Tags: scala, playframework, scala.js

I send form errors from Play side to front end like this:

```
JsError.toJson(errors)
```

And on front end I got something like this:

```
{"obj.comment":[{"msg":["error.minLength"],"args":[10]}],"obj.name":[{"msg":["error.path.missing"],"args":[]}]}
```

I need to know how to check if I have error for specific field and if there is error get messages for this field.

Is it possible to use Play Json in Scala.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Play Json, because it relies on reflection which Scala.js currently doesn't support.

Have a look a `µPickle`. It's a great lightweight JSON parser that works with Scala.js, because it doesn't use reflection. [Check it out here.](http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle-pprint/upickle/)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Could you provide some example how to  read my example error with µPickle?

Comment: You could make a case class with the respective fields and just `read[YourCaseClass](json)` to parse it.